# How to correctly handle my Core Data merge events

Tags: multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperation

I'm using Core Data with child contexts for NSOperations running on a private queue.

I'm not sure if this is the right model so please correct me if I'm wrong and thank you.

I have a core data manager with a managed object context for a private queue and a child managed object context of that for the main queue. I then create grandchild private queue contexts off the child contexts to run operations concurrently on Core Data.

I have 3 operations

- Delete an item
- Add an item
- Get an item (which can also edit/remove an item).

My question is what is the best threading model for these 3 operations? I have a single queue in the manager at the moment running any one of the operations with max concurrency of 1.

Should I use a second queue? more concurrency?

And lastly, where do I add the merge handling? The operations seem to be merging on their own with out any notifications at the moment.